# No main classes found

Tags: java, program-entry-point

This java code should work, but it gives an error:

```
no main classes found.
```

I know there's not specifically a "public static void main" class, but I don't need one here, right?  I'm using NetBeans IDE.

```
public enum Face
{
  TWO(2),
  THREE(3),
  FOUR(4),
  FIVE(5),
  SIX(6),
  SEVEN(7),
  EIGHT(8),
  NINE(9),
  TEN(10),
  JACK(11),
  QUEEN(12),
  KING(13),
  ACE(14);

  private int cardValue;

  private Face (int value)
  {
    this.cardValue = value;
  }

  public int getCardValue() {
    return cardValue;
  }
}

public enum Suit
{
  HEARTS,
  SPADES,
  CLUBS,
  DIAMONDS;
}

public class Card
{
  private Suit suit;
  private Face cardValue;

  public Card (Face cardValue, Suit suit)
  {
    this.cardValue = cardValue;
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  public Suit getSuit()
  {
    return suit;
  }

  public void setSuit(Suit suit)
  {
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  public Face getCardValue()
  {
    return cardValue;
  }

  public void setCardValue(Face cardValue)
  {
    this.cardValue = cardValue;
  }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator; 

public class DeckofCards
{
  private ArrayList<Card> deck;

  public DeckofCards ()
  {
    this.deck = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<13; i++)
    {
      Face value = Face.values()[i];

      for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
      {
        Card card = new Card(value, Suit.values()[j]);
        this.deck.add(card);
      }
    } 

    Collections.shuffle(deck);

    Iterator<Card> cardIterator = deck.iterator();
    while (cardIterator.hasNext())
    {
      Card aCard = cardIterator.next();
      System.out.println(aCard.getCardValue() + " of " + aCard.getSuit());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? The main method is the entry point of an application. You don't need one to compile code, but to begin execution, you need one.

Comment: All Java applications must have a `public static void main` method to be invoked from the command line. For example, to say `java Foo` on the command line, class `Foo` needs a main method. This doesn't apply if you aren't using the command line; class `Bar` will compile and can run *if invoked by other classes*, even with no main method.

Comment: Where did you define the `main()` method in your code?

Comment: You seem to be confused as to what you're trying to do.  You'll be fine if you're trying to create a `playingcards.jar` library, but you're in trouble if you're trying to execute this code as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some inspection it seems that you want to run the code in the `DeckOfCards()` constructor.

Stick in the following code and it will run as expected:

```
public class DeckRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DeckOfCards();
    }
}
```

As a side note, you shouldn't be doing stuff with side effects in your constructor.  I'd take out the following code and place it in the main method (after creating suitable accessor methods):

```
Iterator<Card> cardIterator = deck.iterator();
while (cardIterator.hasNext())
{
  Card aCard = cardIterator.next();
  System.out.println(aCard.getCardValue() + " of " + aCard.getSuit());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You will need a `main` to run this code. It will compile, but you won't be able to run it until you add a `main` because the JVM won't know where to "start" running your code.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you used NetBeans IDE or Eclipse IDE, you have to know that all java app needs main() to run. sometimes you may not find main, as you said Netbeans. probably you used some framework which hided the main().